# Repeat a line in java

Tags: java

I want to learn to code so one of my friends who studies computer science sent me a very long PDF about programming. I started reading and getting into stuff and when I got to the exercices I came upon one that I could not do easily display `welcome` to five times on five lines. I know I could just write `System.out.println` five times but that would be cheating.

Is there a repeat command in Java and how do i use it?

Comment: One basically uses a `for` loop for something like that: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { System.out.println("Welcome"); }`

Comment: I can give you a lead for this, search on `loops`. `for` and `while` are the most common

Comment: What does this long PDF tell you about loops?

Comment: As @deHaar mentioned. You can read about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: *Another cheating possibility*: Provide a `List<String> welcomes;`, add `"Welcome"` 5 times and then do `welcomes.forEach(w -> System.out.println(w));`…

Comment: You can research on: Loops in Java.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a loop for this. e.g. using for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   System.out.println("Welcome to Java");
}
```

You may try out the same exercise using a *while* loop, or a *do-while* loop (google it)

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for JAVA 8

```java
IntStream.range(0, 5)
          .mapToObj(value -> "welcome to java")
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

but it is simple code you could use for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   System.out.println("Welcome to Java");
}
```